# Jquery unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an interval check thats returning and unexpected token error. I'm doing a call to admin-ajax.php every second and I'm expecting to get an integer value + 1 on each check. I've checked the output of the session variable that I'm using to transfer across from another function and that works fine. I know I'm close to nailing this - just failing at the last hurdle. Any help would be great.

Jquery post call function is:

```
 var cjd_interval = null;

function cjd_interval_checker(){                 

            var cjd_email_fans_nonce  = $("#cjd_email_nonce").val();

            var data = {
                'action': 'cjd_update_progress_bar',
                nonce: 'cjd_email_nonce'
            };

            $.post(cjdAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(result);
                $("#cjd-progressbar").attr('value', result);
            });

        };
```

And the PHP function is:

```
function cjd_update_progress_bar() {

  /**
   * Check Permissions
   */
  if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

  $count = $_SESSION['counter'];
  echo json_encode( $count );
  }

  wp_die();       

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cjd_update_progress_bar', 'cjd_update_progress_bar' ); 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cjd_update_progress_bar', 'cjd_update_progress_bar' );
```

Comment: It's `$("#cjd-progressbar").val(result);`, setting the actual value, not the attribute

Comment: console.log(result); try make this response ^^
$("#cjd-progressbar").attr('value', result); this s wrong too, make it response

Comment: Also, you're parsing the JSON into an object, and then using it as a string when you add it as a value, which probably gets you `[object, Object]`, don't parse it.

Comment: Ok - tried this and it's exposed that the $_SESSION['counter'] isn't being set by the parent ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post(cjdAjax.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    var result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(response);
    $("#cjd-progressbar").attr('value', response);
});
```

You've made a typo, you've typed result insteaf of response.

```
    $("#cjd-progressbar").attr('value', response);
```

This can be changed to:

```
    $("#cjd-progressbar").val(response);
```